# What are the requirements on the function f(x) for the L_2 norm of f(x) to be a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, non-convex-optimization

I know that if f is convex and strictly non-negative this is true, additionally if f is affine, then we should also have convexity, however I was hoping for something a bit better. I currently have a function that is strictly convex but not strictly non-negative, does that mean the L_2 norm of this function is neither concave nor convex? Or does that simply mean that we can not say anything about the functions convexity?

Additionally, even if the problem is not convex, if the initial guess for f(x) results in values that are strictly over-estimates, i.e.

$$\underset{x}{\text{min}} \big(\sum(f(x_i) - y_i)^2\big)^{1/2}$$

is ensured to have the property that

$$ f(x_i) - y_i > 0 $$

for all i. Then will the optimization procedure have a better chance of finding a global minimum?

Finally, if I add a constraint to the optimization problem requiring that $ f(x_i) > y_i $, such that I am now solving the problem,

$$\underset{x}{\text{min}} \big(\sum(f(x_i) - y_i)^2\big)^{1/2}$$
subject to: $ f(x) > y $

Will convexity of f(x) be enough to ensure the primal problem is convex? If so are there ways to solve this for a general anonymous function f?

Comment: See the book by Boyd and Vandenberghe on compositions of functions (Section 3.2.4).

Comment: Sorry, you really can't do better. Convexity is *fragile*. It is very, very easy to "break" it by attempting to compose functions in violation of the rules in Boyd & Vandenberghe (for instance). Does that mean B&V has the exhaustive list of such rules? No, perhaps not. But I doubt they missed any of the genuinely _useful_ ones in practice.

Comment: As for the additional question, if $f(x_i) \geq y_i$ your function is convex, so there is no risk of finding a nonglobal minimum.

Comment: @LinAlg I don't think he's asking that. He is saying the _initial point_ satisfies those inequalities, but he's not guaranteeing that the _solution_ does. Without a firm nonnegativity constraint the problem remains nonconvex. I suppose, subjectively, there's a better chance of finding the local minimum, but there is still no guarantee.

Comment: I have read through most of the text by Boyd and Vandenberghe on the topic of compositions of functions, and added the final qualifier asking about including a constraint on f(x) and y. Also, thanks for the info, I really didn't think of just adding a constraint to the problem. With this constraint, is this now a convex problem for $\underline{any}$ f(x) that is convex or is there anything else that I should be concerned with?